# How to include plus sign in CSS class name in selector

Tags: css

I don't know how to place a "+" in my CSS. Take a closer look at the "Donator+" div.

```
body
{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: "Arial", serif;
} 

.nav
{
     background-color: #595959;
     color: #ffffff;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
     border-bottom: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
}

.nav > li
{
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0 25px 0 25px;   
}

.nav > li > a
{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #ffffff;
}

.nav > li > a:hover
{
     color: #1b1b1b
}

.line
{  
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #353535;
}

.image
{
     display: block;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}

div.vip
{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: 215px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

div.price-vip
{
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 85%;
}

div.name-vip
{
     margin-top: 20px;
     font-size: 85%;
     font-weight: bold;
}


div.donator
{
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: left;
     width: 190px;
     height: 165px;
     margin-left: 320px;
     margin-top: 70px;
}

div.price-donator
{
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 85%;
}


div.name-donator
{
     font-size: 85%;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top: 20px;
}

div.donator+
{
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: left;
     width: 190px;
     height: 165px;
     margin-left: 320px;
     margin-top: 70px;      
}

div.price-donator+
{
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 85%;
}

div.name-donator+
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that symbol? Is it part of your class name?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape the character in your selector:

```
div.name-donator\+ {
```

but don't escape it in the HTML:

```
<div class="name-donator+">
```

Answer (score 0):

See I don't know what you are trying, but here is little explanation regarding `css + selector`,

**element + element** - *selects all elements that are immediately placed after another element parent element*, not parent element and child inside of it, to select and style child element you have to use `css > selector`.

```css
.div1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#111;
}

.div2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f2f;
}

.div1 + .div2{
  background:#f22;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>

<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: This is not the question. He is wondering about using a plus sign in a class name (I think).

Comment: @torazaburo might be.

Comment: @torazaburo OP hasn't answered on that yet, if OP clears that the answer given by you is what he was searching for then I will remove mine and it get easy for upcoming users to refer correct method of doing that.